# how define new type based on interface with some modifications

Tags: typescript

I have this interface

```
interface Store {
    ReducerFoo : ReducerFooState;
    ReducerBar : ReducerBarState;
    ReducerTest : ReducerTestState;
}
```

now I want to define object its properties look like this

```
 [KeyName] : () => [TypeOfKey]
```

for example **`FooReducer`**

```
ReducerFoo : () => ReducerFooState
```

so the type of my object should be like this

```
{
    ReducerFoo : () => ReducerFooState;
    ReducerBar : () => ReducerBarState;
    ReducerTest : () => ReducerTestState;
}
```

can I do something like this without the need to define another interface that describes my object?

I need this because the `Store` interface will be evolved as my app grow and I don't want to change two thing any time I add a new property to the `Store` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type StoreFunctions = {
  [K in keyof Store]: () => Store[K];
}
```

When you add new properties to the Store interface, this mapped type doesn't need to be changed.